# FSCANF Problems reading in Apostrophes and Hyphens?

Tags: c++, c, string, scanf

```
     int i = 0;


     while (fscanf(input, "%c", &letter) == 1){

           if(isalpha(letter)) {


           if( letter != '\'' && letter != '-' ) {                                 
           text[i] = tolower(letter);
           i++;
           }                                 

           }

}
```

I am trying to read in a block of text from a file and then output them in all lowercase with no special characters or spaces. It works on everything except for ' and - characters. On the output they look like the u with the ^ over it, and the AE symbol... (ASCII values 146 and 150 I think, which I still can't catch with if logic, for some reason.)

Is FSCANF not able to handle these characters, or am I missing something?

Comment: It should be able to read those characters correctly.  However, the isalpha call would, I believe, cause the shown code to ignore those characters.

Comment: I thought so too, but these characters are still showing up in my output. Oddly, even when I remove the tolower() call, the original apostrophes and hyphens do not show up.

Comment: Is the input true text, or is it the output of a word processor that may have done "smart" substitution on the hyphen and apostrophe?  For example, Word is notorious for that; if the input was made in Word, those may not be the characters you think they are.

Comment: That was exactly the issue Erik. Thanks a lot, I should have suspected something when Notepad had issues picking up on the hyphens and apostrophes. I copypasted the text from a .pdf file, so that explains why it did not work.

Comment: Just a note.  ASCII proper is only 0 to 127.

Comment: Pedantically, `isalpha(letter)` is UB (undefined behavior) with `char` when it is signed.  Better to use `isalpha((unsigned char)letter)` - it might help in your case.   --- Ahhh but I see you have solved things.  Suggest posting your own answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
while((letter = fgetc(input)) != EOF){/***/}
```

(if you read text file (not binary))